# C++: inheritance or class member for C struct?

Tags: c++, inheritance, struct

I have a plain old C `struct`:

```
struct eggplant {
    double *ptr1;
    double *ptr2;
    ... // many more
}
```

and a function that manages the allocation the memory pointed to by the pointers, and returns a new `eggplant` instance:

```
struct eggplant *create_eggplant(int n);
```

The above function allocates a chunk of memory (including space for the newly created struct) and distributes it to the pointers.

---

I want to extend `struct eggplant` in C++11. I could do that by keeping a pointer to the struct as a

### member:

```
class EggPlant {
    ...
    private :
        struct eggplant *plant;
}
```

or I could try via

### inheritance:

```
class EggPlant : private struct eggplant {
    ...    
}
```

The first option allows me to use the `create_eggplant` function. However, the second option looks more straightforward from a conceptual point of view (the class EggPlant *is* an eggplant, it doesn't *have* one).

I tried

```
this = create_eggplant(...);
```

in the constructor but that does not work for the obvious reason that you cannot overwrite a pointer to a class that you are constructing (`lvalue required`).

**Can I inherit the `struct` but still use my `create_eggplant` function in some useful way? Or, is it anyway better to keep a pointer to the struct?**

Comment: In c++, use smart pointers instead of raw owning pointers.

Comment: `EggPlant() : eggplant(*create_eggplant(..)) {}` (Forgetting memleak)

Comment: `private struct eggplant` make that `private eggplant`, there's no need for `struct` here. It's only required to disambiguate between types and functions, like `struct stat` vs. `stat()`.

Comment: you dont need to say `struct eggplant *plant` - `eggplant *plant` is enough in c++

Comment: it would be nice to see the allocate function (create_eggplant)

Comment: as a reminder (or maybe new info) - in c++ class and struct as basically the same thing (just the default is private for members in class and public in struct). Just in case you are thinking that class and struct are radically different things

Comment: It's not just for members, but also for inheritance, @pm100. In `class ... : private ...` it is thus redundant, for example.

Comment: You said "the class EggPlant _is_ an eggplant," in which case `private` inheritance is not the right model. Use public inheritance for IS-A relationships. But I don't think IS-A is right here, because you need to encapsulate the `eggplant` type in order to ensure the memory management is don'e correctly.

Comment: How does `create_eggplant` handle the allocation? If `eggplant`s don't need a very specific allocation scheme, then taking the choice of allocation from the caller is bad design. At the very least there should be an `init_eggplant` that does default initialization only. Then you could have had your inheritance based scheme work. But if the `eggplant` objects need to all be allocated with a specific allocator, you shouldn't think about inheritance. Go the composition route.

Comment: @pm100 Thanks for the reminder but so much I knew about C++ :p

Answer (score 4):

Your choice to have `struct eggplant *create_eggplant(int n);` manage its own memory is in conflict with C++ inheritance.  Inheritance *also* implies management of the location of the base object.

If you changed your C function to return a copy:

```
struct eggplant create_eggplant(int n);
```

You could also inherit from that class:

```
class EggPlant : private eggplant {
    EggPlant(int n) : eggplant{ create_eggplant(n) }
    {
    }
    ...    
};
```

Comment: I like your suggestion, it is clean. However, with the function returning a pointer-to-struct, I can clean it up with a simple `free(new_eggplant)`. Returning a copy (and thus having a shallow copy), wouldn't I lose track of the pointer returned by `malloc` inside `create_eggplant`?

Comment: @Nibor in this proposed answer, `create_eggplant` would no longer need or have a `malloc`.  You are correct that you would not be able to clean up `eggplant` separately from cleaning up `EggPlant`.

Answer (score 1):

No, you would need a new function if you wish to inherit. If you must use the existing function a member is the best you will be able to manage.

Comment: Is this a common (anti-)pattern?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> struct eggplant *create_eggplant(int n);
> ```

Should be just:

```
eggplant *create_eggplant(int n);
```

This isn't C, you don't have to type `struct` everywhere.

> However, the second option looks more straightforward from a
>   conceptual point of view (the class `EggPlant` is an eggplant, it
>   doesn't have one).

That's wrong. **Only public inheritance models *is-a*.** Private inheritance models *has-a* or *is-implemented-in-terms-of*.

> Can I inherit the struct but still use my create_eggplant function in some useful way?

No, not in a useful way, especially as your description of `create_eggplant` sounds like `malloc` is used in it.

> Or, is it anyway better to keep a pointer to the struct?

No, pointers make code more complicated.

If you want to use private inheritance, then either add a constructor to `eggplant` that more or less does what `create_eggplant` does now, except of allocating memory for the `eggplant` itself, or modify `create_eggplant` to become something like `void init_eggplant(eggplant& e)`, then do this in the constructor of `EggPlant`:

```
EggPlant::EggPlant() :
    eggplant()
{
    init_eggplant(*this);
}
```

Or just don't use private inheritance but a normal data member:

```
class EggPlant
{
    // ...
private:
    eggplant my_eggplant;
}
```

As you can see, the common goal of all solutions is to get rid of the dynamic memory allocation for `eggplant`.